# Shortcut for duplicating line UP in notepad++

Tags: eclipse, notepad++, shortcut

I am aware that you can duplicate a line in notepad++ with the Ctrl+D shortcut. It duplicates the line and places the duplicate below the current line.

In eclipse you can do the same thing with the Ctrl+Alt+Down shortcut. But in eclipse you can also duplicate a line so that it is placed above the current line with the Ctrl+Alt+Up shortcut.

**Is there such a shortcut (duplicate line up) in notepad++?**

Best regards,
Mattias

Comment: What is the advantage of having above rather than below?

Comment: The duplicate line shortcut is used when you want to insert a line that is almost identical to another line, either below or above the original line. It is just a convenient to be able to create the copy above or below the original line depending on where you need it.

However I noticed that the cursur is left on the original line when the duplicate line is created below. In eclipse the cursur is moved down or up with the duplicated line.

So in this case if I want the line above I just duplicate and start editing the line the cursur is on. If I want it below I move down one line and edit.